# Filtering Data by multiple columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm working on a powerBI dashboard where a central visualization of risk areas needs to be filtered by auditor. Pretty simple so far. My problem, is that the data is being drawn from a database of checklists that store both auditor and risk areas in the same column, which on the DB side of things are identified by the questions column, and grouped by the checklistID. Example below:

```
CheckID Question        Answer
001     Auditor?        Mark
001     Fire Hazard     Risk
001     Slip Hazard     Safe
001     Machine Guard   Risk
002     Auditor?        Anthony
002     Fire Hazard     Safe
002     Slip Hazard     Safe
002     Machine Guard   Risk
```

So the central visual filters out auditor (as well as many other rows, I've dumbed it down for the example) to chart how the different risk areas stack up against each other across all checkIDs. But I need to be able to filter for one or more specific auditors on that display. A bit of googling around has pushed me towards slicers and calculated fields, but the guides on how to set those up do not cover the situation where all my relevant data is in the same column.

Effectively what I need is a filter that filters out rows based on checkIDs where the 'Auditor?' question of that checkID = X. Any help is appreciated, I'm still pretty new to the deeper workings of powerBI!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Power Query, reference your original query and keep only rows where `Question = Auditor?`. The resulting dimension table will look like this:

| CheckID | Question | Answer ( = Auditor ) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Auditor? | Mark |
| 002 | Auditor? | Anthony |

You can keep or remove the `Question` column after filtering - but I recommend renaming `Answer` to `Auditor` to make it clearer what this column now contains.

After this, reference your original query again, and this time remove rows where `Question = Auditor?`. The resulting fact table will have the rest of the information:

| CheckID | Question | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Fire Hazard | Risk |
| 001 | Slip Hazard | Safe |
| 001 | Machine Guard | Risk |
| 002 | Fire Hazard | Safe |
| 002 | Slip Hazard | Safe |
| 002 | Machine Guard | Risk |

Now you have two tables, one dimension table that gives you information about the auditor per `CheckID`, and one fact table that gives you information relating to the `CheckID`.

Save and apply the changes in Power Query and create a relationship between the `CheckID` columns. At this point you can create one table visual with `CheckID, Question, Answer` from the fact table. To slice this table, create a table where you only use the `Auditor` column from the dimension table, and click on e.g. "Mark" to apply a filter to the fact table.